# AngularJS -> Capturing when DOM has finished rendering elements in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

We're using AngularJS to render a schedule table with ng-repeat.

I also need to call an initialization function for a jQuery plugin that acts on the DOM objects being rendered by the Angular code.

However, I do not know how to make it call this initialization until AFTER the DOM objects have been created because the plugin requires the DOM elements to be built before initialization.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can use `$timeout` which won't run until element exists

```
app.directive('makeMeGreen',function($timeout){
  return{
    restrict:'A',
    link:function(scope,elem,attrs){
       $timeout(function(){
         elem.makeMeGreen();
       },0)
  }
  } 
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/tvLPwnBueNIhU3zIwCH0?p=preview)**</kbd>

Alternate approach is to $observe attributes

Comment: ultra simple plugin I quickly made ...see demo

Comment: It isn't working. I cannot create a fiddle to demonstrate. The issue is I only want to run one function after all the DOM objects are created. Not when each are finished being created.

Comment: try this version  .. http://plnkr.co/edit/tvLPwnBueNIhU3zIwCH0?p=preview. Checks for last element in repeater, then appends to parent

Comment: provide more details about plugin and your app. Very hard to help without more detail